# Which one is the stronger base?

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbonyl-compounds, organic-reduction

I'm studying Wolff-Kishner reduction and I don't understand why after this step
[image]
the leaving group is $\ce{OH-}$ instead of $\ce{^-HN-NH2}$. I guess it's because hydroxide ion is less strong than the other although it would be useful to know if i can calculate pkb of diazanide (namely $\ce{^-NH-NH2}$) starting from data on hydrazine. Also I'm considering pkb of $\ce{OH-}$ equal to $0$ because it's acting as a base.

Comment: It's rather called hydrazide. They're stronger bases then respective alkoxides (and OH-).

Comment: A hydrazide is a derivative of a carboxylic acid [RC(=O)NHNH2]. A hydrazone is a derivative of a ketone [R2C=NNH2] or aldehyde [RHC=NNH2]. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Mirko: The mechanism you present for the early stages of the Wolff-Kishner Reduction includes hydroxide necessary for the decomposition of the yet to be formed hydrazone **6** of the ketone **1** (or aldehyde). One may preform the hydrazone and then do the actual reduction in the presence of hydroxide in a high boiling hydroxylic solvent (Huang-Minlon variation<sup>[1](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja01216a013?journalCode=jacsat&quickLinkVolume=68&quickLinkPage=2487&selectedTab=citation&volume=68)</sup>).
[image: ![enter image description here]
The mechanism for hydrazone formation is a reversible reaction and is often conducted by removal of water to shift the equilibrium to the right.<sup>2</sup> Realizing that most commercial hydrazine contains 15% water, it can act as the agent for proton exchange in adduct **3**. One need only use the electron pair in structure **4** to eject hydroxide contrary to the elimination proposed in the last step of your mechanism. There is no need to be concerned about the anion of hydrazine as a leaving group. Hydroxide only has to deprotonate the acid **5**.

1) [Huang-Minlon, *J. Am. Chem. Soc.*, **1946**, *68*, 2487.](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja01216a013?journalCode=jacsat&quickLinkVolume=68&quickLinkPage=2487&selectedTab=citation&volume=68)
2) Hydrazones and oximes are not as susceptible to hydrolysis as are imines owing to the resonance stabilization provided by the second heteroatom.